# Many to Many Polymorphic Models - Setting up factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, factory-bot

I was looking around and have set up a polymorphic many to many model which seems to work. I set it up like so:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_categoryable
  has_many :blogs, :through=>:category_categoryable
  has_many :language, :through=>:category_categoryable

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_categoryable, :as=>:categoryable
  has_many :category, :through=>:category_categoryable

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :category_categoryable, :as=>:categoryable
  has_many :category, :through=>:category_categoryable

class CategoryCategoryable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :blog, :polymorphic=>true
  belongs_to :language, :polymorphic=>true
```

is there any reason why I shouldn't do that, also I can't work out how to set up factory girl up I've tried this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :blog do 
    sequence(:title) {|b| "Blog name #{b}" }
    content "blog content"
    meta "meta content"
    publish_date Date.parse("2011-05-02")
    displayit true

    after_create {|a| Factory(:category, :categoryable=>a)}
  end
end


FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
   sequence(:name) {|n| "category#{n}" }
  end
end


FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :categories_categoryables do 
    association :category
    association :categoryable, :factory => :blog 
  end
end
```

But I can't seem to get it to work, has anyone got any idea how I might set it up? I not sure if I have the after create in the right place, I've tried calling it in the categories_categoryables, but that didn't seem to help either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You still need to define the factory for your category when you do the association. Something like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :categories_categoryables do 
    association :category, :factory => :category
    association :categoryable, :factory => :blog 
  end
end
```

At least, this is how I have it set up in my factories.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to help.  I think there is something wrong with my after call in blog but I can't figure out how I am supposed to fix it